# Render shadows of objects culled by camera

Tags: unity-game-engine

My setup is as follows:

- Two layers with `GameObjects` in them: `walls` and `shortWalls`
- Single camera, which is culling either `walls` or `shortWalls`
- Single light, which is culling `shortWalls`

The effect I'm trying to create is a room where the walls can be fully rendered `walls` or only render the lowest part `shortWalls` (kind of like The Sims wall height).

The problem I am facing is that, when I change the camera culling mask to ignore `walls`, the light seems to ignore `walls` too. The culling mask of this light is constant, set to ignore `shortWalls` and to illuminate and cast shadows from `walls`.

I assume that, since the [Unity Manual's layers page](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html) separates the use of layers by cameras and lights, the functionality is separated too. But it seems that the camera is ignoring the shadows cast by an object that is being culled.

**Is there any way to allow the camera to render shadows casts by objects that are culled by the camera (but not the light)?**